# Any way to extract underlying Xaml?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, runtime

Is there anyway to extract the underlying xaml from a control.

IE. I have a textbox named fooBox. Can I get xaml back from the textbox at runtime that represents the textbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This shows you the full lifecycle (from control to XAML back to control).
As you can see,

```
string s = XamlWriter.Save(value);
```

is the interesting part you might care about.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Clones a given UIElement.  Please note that any events, animations, etc
    /// on the source item may not carry over to the cloned object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">UIElement to clone.</param>
    /// <returns>A shallow clone of the source element.</returns>
    public static UIElement CloneUIElement(UIElement value)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        string s = XamlWriter.Save(value);
        StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(s);
        XmlReader xmlReader = XmlTextReader.Create(stringReader, new XmlReaderSettings());
        return (UIElement)XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For Silverlight, I ran across [this blog post](http://blogs.windowsclient.net/rob_relyea/archive/2010/07/29/xamlwriter-save-for-silverlight.aspx) by Rob Relyea that referred to a [Silverlight xaml serializer](http://www.davidpoll.com/2010/07/25/to-xaml-with-love-an-experiment-with-xaml-serialization-in-silverlight/) created by David Poll. Huge kudos to David Poll. ([Downloads Page](http://www.davidpoll.com/downloads-and-samples/#SLaB)).

Usage

```
UiXamlSerializer uxs = new UiXamlSerializer();
string text = uxs.Serialize(this.gridToSerialize);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes - Josh Smith does this in his Mole tool:  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/MoleForWPF.aspx