# How to render a databound XAML control to a native XAML drawing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, binding

I have a data bound XAML control like this:

```
<UserControl>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" />
</UserControl>
```

and want it to render as a 'drawing' like this:

```
<UserControl>
    <TextBlock Text="Actual text value" />
</UserControl>
```

Does anyone know how to extract the drawing from an arbitrary control?

UPDATE:
This question does not seem to be clear. So I try to explain a bit more. 
The input is a XAML control with databinding. Now I want to convert this to plain XAML without any databinding. The output can be written to disk and displayed by any application which understands XAML, without binding to anything.

So the solution should look something like this:

```
FrameworkElementinput = (FrameworkElement)XamlReader.Read(inputFile);
input.DataContext = dataObject;
FrameworkElement output = ConvertToNative(input);
XamlWriter.Write(outputFile, output);
```

I'm looking for an implementation of 'ConvertToNative'

Comment: Confused on what you mean by drawing? In your example the binding is simple a runtime resolution on what should be provided within the Text property; whereas you're providing the value at compile time in the second example

Comment: From where and when do you want this? From inside Visual Studio 2010 Designer produced by DesignTime data?

Comment: @Aaron I don't know the exact terms. With 'drawing' I mean plain XAML, without any extensions, like binding. The 'drawing' should be loadable in a context where the data is unknown. (Like a foreign application.)

Comment: @Meleak This need's to be done at runtime

Comment: @Michael When you bind the data to a given property on your model that data can come from anywhere and will be executed at runtime. So you could have {Binding GetMeSomethingFarFarAway} where GetMeSomethingFarFarAway is a property on your model which in turn calls a service which then makes a call to Flickr and gets an image name.

Comment: Ok, do you want the actual `UserControl` to be rendered as a Drawing or do you want a drawing of the Xaml code you posted at the end?

Comment: @Meleak I don't think an actual drawing is wanted here...I could be wrong... trying to read between the lines...

Comment: @Aaron, I'm lost either way trying to figure this one out :) What's your interpretation?

Comment: @Meleak Wait I think I got it! The OP wants essentially a screen shot of the bottom portion so they could display within their application. So the control does what it normally does and evaluates the binding; now display the XAML for that given control in a view that can be seen by a user of the application based on the evaluated binding. If that is the case...it can be seen here...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/783497/any-way-to-extract-underlying-xaml

Comment: Sorry for confusing you. Maybe 'render' is the wrong verb here. The output should be xaml (text) and must not contain any bindings. I updated the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're gonna do this for a `UserControl`s, make sure to remove the x:Class attribute first since you'll get a `XamlParseException` otherwise.

You can load the Xaml file with `XamlReader.Load` and when you save it with `XamlWriter.Save`, the Bindings are translated to their actual value. There seems to be some trouble getting the Bindings to update though so I worked around this by subscribing to the Loaded event and add it to a container in the UI, and in the event handler remove if from the container and then save it. This can probably be worked around in a better way though..

```
private void SomeMethod()
{
    CreateXamlWithBindingValues("UserControl1.xaml", "UserControl1_Saved.xaml");
}
private void CreateXamlWithBindingValues(string sourcePath, string savePath)
{
    StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(sourcePath);
    StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
    XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
    FrameworkElement loadedObject = (FrameworkElement)XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);
    loadedObject.DataContext = UserControlViewModel;

    RoutedEventHandler routedEventHandler = null;
    routedEventHandler = new RoutedEventHandler(delegate
    {
        loadedObject.Loaded -= routedEventHandler;
        grid1.Children.Remove(loadedObject);

        string savedObject = XamlWriter.Save(loadedObject);
        StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(savePath);
        streamWriter.Write(savedObject);
        streamWriter.Close();
    });
    loadedObject.Loaded += routedEventHandler;
    grid1.Children.Add(loadedObject);
}
```

**Xaml before Save**

```
<UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**Xaml after Save** *As you can see, there's no linebreaks but the Text value is the value produced from the binding*

```
<UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"><Grid><TextBlock Text="Actual Text Value" /></Grid></UserControl>
```

**Xaml before Save**

```
<Grid Name="grid1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <Button Content="{Binding MyContent}"/>
</Grid>
```

**Xaml after Save**

```
<Grid Name="grid1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"><Button>Actual Content</Button></Grid>
```